# Several actions with same name in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-redux-form

I have actions from different packages which have the same name like this:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { setActiveLanguage } from 'react-localize-redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../actions/actionCreators';
import * as toggleActions from '../actions/toggleActions';
import {actions as rrfActions} from 'react-redux-form';

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators(
      {
        ...actionCreators,
        ...toggleActions,
        setActiveLanguage,
        ...rrfActions
      },
      dispatch);
  }

export default mapDispatchToProps
```

As both `toggleActions` and `rrfActions` have a `toggle` action, nesting the `rrfActions` could do the trick (?) to call the action, but I can't prevent the reducers from listening to the same `TOGGLE` action type. Is there a workaround other than not having a general `mapDispatchToProps` for all connected components, rather very specific ones

Cheers!

Comment: if both actions dispatch the same type and you want your reducer to ignore one of them, it won't help to change how you bind or "hide" inside the `mapDispatchToProps` or `bindActionCreators`. if you have access to edit one of them just use a `meta` property and handle the action that has this meta. for example: `dispatch{type:'toggle', meta: 'myToggle'}`

Answer (score 1):

Same action types are being served by same reducer listeners by design of the redux. If you want different listeners to be responsible for your actions, that actions must have different types. Why don't you want to use prefixes/suffixes?

```
MY_SIMPLE_ACTION
MY_SIMPLE_ACTION_AREA1
MY_SIMPLE_ACTION_AREA2
```

In action dispatcher you may pass an additional argument specifying the area:

```
export function onDoSomething(param1, param2, referer) {
  return dispatch({
    type: MY_SIMPLE_ACTION + (referer ? `_${referer}` : ''),
    payload: { param1, param2 }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, namespace the **value** of your action constant

```
const TOGGLE = 'namespace/TOGGLE'
```

Then, if you define your reducer like so

```
const TOGGLE = 'namespace/TOGGLE'

switch (action.type) {
    case TOGGLE:
        // do_stuff
}
```

The property `action.type` must evaluate to precisely `'namespace/TOGGLE'`.

It's very unlikely that the value of the `TOGGLE` action from **react-redux-form** contains your unique namespace, right?

Your reducer is now safe.

---

Sources

- https://itnext.io/namespacing-redux-action-type-constant-values-90b932eea43f
- https://jaketrent.com/post/namespace-redux-action-types/

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this was with renaming actions:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { setActiveLanguage } from 'react-localize-redux';
import * as actionCreators from '../actions/actionCreators';
import * as toggleActions from '../actions/toggleActions';
import { actions as rrfActions } from 'react-redux-form';

let renamedActions = {};
Object.keys(rrfActions).map((v,k)=> {
  renamedActions['rrf' + v.replace(/\b\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase())] = rrfActions[v]
  // toggle -> rrfToggle
  return null;
})

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      ...actionCreators,
      ...toggleActions,
      setActiveLanguage,
      ...renamedActions
    },
    dispatch);
}

export default mapDispatchToProps
```